# Stop a process by port from javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I'm using jest to write some tests for a node.js application. I have a server `server.js` and a test file `server.test.js`. In my `server.js` I use the line

```
    var secureServer = https.createServer(options, 
    app).listen(config.node_port, () => {
    logger.info("Service running on " + config.node_port)
    });
```

to start my server on port 8082. In `server.test.js` I use

```
    var posClient = require('./pos-ClientJS.js');
```

to get access to the functions, that I have to test. When I run my test I get the following console output:

```
    Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.

    This usually means that there are asynchronous operations that weren't 
    stopped in your tests. Consider running Jest with `-- 
    detectOpenHandles` to troubleshoot this issue.
```

So my question is: Is there a way to stop the server running with javascript code like `stop(8082)` or sth.? Or is there a less difficult way to solve this problem without stopping the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Nodejs [HTTP](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_close_callback) module documentation, you can call `secureServer.close()` to stop listening at the specified port. If the module exposes the server to Jest, you can use the [teardown](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/setup-teardown.html) methods to stop the server automatically after tests complete.